# How do I save a file in Flex with Flash 9

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using Flex 3 under Flash Player 9.

I have a datagrid that I want to export to Excel. I construct the Excel object (`ByteArray`) in Actionscript, and now I want to save it using `FileReference`. However, under FlashPlayer 9, `FileReference` only has a `download` method. Can I somehow point this download method to the Excel object?

Comment: Are you trying to write the data to disk as a csv/.xls file? That is not possible if you have a Flex app.

Comment: But you can download and save files from within Flex, right? That's the workaround I'm asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to upload your data to your server, and then download it to your client.  Look at [this example](http://designreviver.com/tutorials/actionscript-3-jpeg-encoder-revealed-saving-images-from-flash/) for saving images created in as3 to a client.

OR *(this is hackish, but might get done what you need)* you can print your data to the debug console.